# how to update git client to overcome the latest vulnerability?

Tags: macos, git, github

Recently GitHub recommended us to update the git client on our machines.
[news on vulnerability](https://github.com/blog/1938-git-client-vulnerability-announced)

So I type in console

```
git --version     //getting 2.0.1
which git     //getting /usr/local/git/bin/git
```

Then I upload one from here(2.2.1, for instance):

[The Git core team site](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/)

I unzip it and then I cant figure it out where to put unzipped files because files under */usr/local/git* are so different,
**what do I need to do to install it?**

**Update:** for everyone curious about my question, [this particular link](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git#Installing-from-Source) have the answers

Comment: RE: the close vote - From the Help Center: "but if your question generally covers... software tools commonly used by programmers" -- this question is definitely on topic. Git is a tool for programmers. And this is an answerable question.

Comment: @GregBurghardt The point is moot. This is more about installing/upgrading Git than actually using it. Plus, I believe that a very similar question was migrated to SuperUser earlier today.

Comment: @Jubobs the question was about command line  and installing from source, but I wasnt familiar with it; So, the command line is the tool for programmers

Comment: Git is a tool for programmers as well. I think this is one area where StackOverflow and SuperUser overlap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you appear to be using Linux (or maybe Max OSX) you'll need to use one of the package managers. The [Download page for Git on Linux](http://git-scm.com/download/linux) has more information.

For Mac OS you'll need to use Homebrew or MacPorts.

Otherwise you'll have to download the source code, `make` and `make install` the newest version of Git if the Linux and Mac package managers don't have the newest release listed.

[Installing Git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git)

Comment: I appreciate your answer, thank you, was very helpful;
This `make` and `make install` and installing from source in general are the topics I wasnt familiar with